# Appropriate effect size to report for permutation tests (Anova specifically)

Tags: anova, effect-size, ancova, permutation-test

#### Original question, with explanation of outcome and explanatory variables included.

Suppose I have a neuroimaging dataset, e.g. diffusion tensor-derived measure for multiple white matter bundles (or tracts) of interest, that I wish to compare between two groups while controlling for biological factors such as age. The outcome variables are:

1. Tract Volume,
2. Fractional Anisotropy (FA),
3. Mean diffusivity (MD),
4. Radial Diffusivity (RD), and
5. Axial Diffusivity (AD).

FA quantifies the degree of anisotropy of diffusion in a given voxel (0 for completely isotropic diffusion, 1 for completely anisotropic). MD, the average of all 3 Diffusion Tensor eigenvalues, quantifies “bulk diffusion” in a voxel. RD, the average of the 2nd and 3rd eigenvalues, quantifies average “perpendicular diffusivity” in a given voxel. Finally, AD, the value of the first eigenvalue, quantifies the amount of “parallel diffusion” in a given voxel. FA, MD, RD, and AD values are derived from quantitative maps, averaged across the entire tract of interest.

Explanatory variables are:

1. Measure quantifying in-scanner motion,
2. Version of the MRI acquisition protocol used (categorical, 2 levels),
3. De-meaned age at scan, and
4. Diagnostic status (categorical, 2 levels).

A sizeable portion of the models I run have either non-normal residuals or display heteroskedasticity. Therefore, I chose to run permutation Anova/Ancova.

I wish to additionally report an effect size. Would partial eta squared be appropriate for permutation Anova/Ancova, or is there a more suitable (non-parametric?) effect size I can report?

#### Addressing specific comment:

I am running an Ancova model using the formula: 1 + Motion + Protocol + Age_centered + Diagnosis. I have 14 tracts (white matter bundles) of interest, of which I have 5 dependent measures for, so 70 individual Ancova models are ran. Around 10-25 models display either nonnormal residuals or heteroskedasticity. I experimented with weighted least squares and Anova/Ancova with white-correction as well. I finally decided on permutation Anova/Ancova, which a colleague suggested I do for all other models.

Comment: Can you describe your outcome variable a bit more?  Have you tried any transformations of your data or other assumption remediation techniques?  The permutation test is a non-parametric test and while using is simple and effective, it can result in loss of power compared to models that make distributional assumptions.  If you can tell us a bit more about your models and your data, we may be able to provide some better guidance.

Comment: Apples to apples comparisons are generally a good goal. It would make sense to report the value of the observed statistic, along with the results of the permutation test on it.